# jQuery selector to get all scripts as text off of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a webpage like this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="script/text" src="http://www.seantburke.com/j.js"></script>
        <script type="script/text">
            $(document).ready({var foo;});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var s = "some more javascript here";
        </script>
        <script type="script/text" src="http://www.seantburke.com/otherjs.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to select all the scripts off of the page including the attributes and innerHTML as text. Is there a simple jQuery function that I am missing?

Desired Output:

```
<script type="script/text"
src="http://www.seantburke.com/j.js"></script><script
type="script/text">$(document).ready({var foo;});</script><script>var
s = "some more javascript here";</script><script type="script/text"
src="http://www.seantburke.com/otherjs.js"></script>
```

These were my attempts at getting it but each do not get the desired output:

```
$('script').text() //gives all innerHTML
$('script') //gives an Array of HTMLScriptElement
$('script')[0].outerHTML //gives the outerHTML as a string for only the first element.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var arr = $('script').map(function() {
              return this.outerHTML;
          }).get();
```

Gets you an array of all the outerHTML for each tag, if you want a single string use `arr.join()`